# Adding new objects into a JSON file via Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I'd like to add new objects into a JSON file using Javascript.

Here's my JSON file

```
{ 
  "l1":{ "Name":"Jack", "Number":"234-234-2342" }


}
```

I'd like to add the following via Javascript-

```
"l2":{ "Name":"Tom", "Number":"534-354-6456" }
```

Also, the original object, "l1", needs to have a comma after its closing bracket.  How can I add this with JS?  Or maybe using JSON for this method is not best practice?  Hoping for some insight, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Read the file
2. Use `JSON.parse` to convert it to a JavaScript object
3. Add the new property (`foo.l2 = { "Name":"Tom", "Number":"534-354-6456" };`)
4. Convert back to JSON with `JSON.stringify`
5. Write back to the file

You are likely to want to implement file locking to avoid having two processes try to edit the file at the same time.

It is usually desirable to use a real database and generate JSON from it on demand.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking to do.  I guess more of my question lies within what the syntax of this operation looks like.  What is the significance of the "foo.l2" part of that code?

Comment: @AlexEdwards — Aside from the reading and writing of files, which depends on which API you use (which depends on the JS environment you are working in), that is more or less the syntax. It isn't hard to find [documentation for the JSON object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) and the arguments those methods take are pretty obvious anyway. `foo` is just a [placeholder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable) for whatever variable you decide to use. `l2` is something you came up with.

Comment: Just working with regular JS and in my case XMLHttpRequest for the Ajax call.  The key is the ability to write back properties to a Json file that's sitting in my main site directory.  It's so a user can add an object through JS, and the JS can reference the added object down the road.  Additionally, I want this added object to be referenced by all users, hence why it is sitting out in the .json file.  It's pretty much a pseudo-database.  Would it maybe be worth implementing SQL in this scenario instead of the Json file approach?  Thanks for bearing with me, i'm a newbie to programming.

Comment: A typical webserver doesn't let you write data to arbitrary files. That would be a ridiculous security hole. You would generally write a web service which does the work for you.

Comment: Understood..thanks for your direction, I appreciate it.